# Casting a string as a static variable

Tags: c#, types, casting, unity-game-engine, static

I am making a game with upgrades, I have class call "GlobalStats" which contains the static variables I need to reference.

I have made another class "MenuUpgrade" that needs to reference these variables, but I want to define which variables are referenced in the editor and not in code, this is so I don't have to duplicate everything 50+ times, and hence the class has to be use generic variables without references to particular static variables.

How can I cast a generic variable in my non-static class as a static variable?

```
public class GlobalStats : MonoBehaviour   
{
    // Static Variable

    public static int maxSpeedLevel = 0;
    public static float playerMaxSpeed = 12.5f;
}


public class MenuUpgrade : MonoBehaviour  
{
    // Generic Variables

    public string upgradeLevel;
    public string upgradeStat;
}
```

Ideally my code would look something like this

```
if(GlobalStats.upgradeLevel == 0)
```

I'm referencing the class, but I get to assign the variable that's being referenced from that class outside of the code in the game editor i'm using.

Here's the function I need it for

```
public void Upgrade()
{
    // Deny Speed Upgrade!
    if(GlobalStats.cash < upgradePrice.GetType() || upgradeLevel.GetType() == 5)
    {
        audio.PlayOneShot(deny, 1f);
    }

    // Buy Speed Upgrade!
    if(GlobalStats.cash >= upgradePrice.GetType() && upgradeLevel.GetType() < 5)
    {
        upgradeStat.GetType() += 1.25f;
        GlobalStats.cash -= upgradePrice.GetType();
        upgradePrice.GetType() *= 2;
        upgradeLevel.GetType() += 1;
        bSwitchSprite = true;
        audio.PlayOneShot(click, 1f);
        audio.PlayOneShot(drill, 1f);
    }

    if(upgradeLevel.GetType() < 5)
    {
        costText.text = upgradePrice.GetType();
    }

    if(upgradeLevel.GetType() >= 5)
    {
        descriptionText.text = "Max Speed Fully Upgraded";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It seems like what you really want to do is use depency injection and a singleton for the MenuUpgrade.  Are you using Autofac or Ninject?

Comment: Also, you might want to research getters and setters.  They would be very useful in this case.

Comment: I'm using Unity, I've never heard of Autofac or Ninject. d:

Could you perhaps explain how to use a depency injection and singleton briefly?

Comment: I don't get your problem. What is it that you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance   tl;dr.  Using a singleton means you can create the class once,  and then reference the same object (no new()ing up an instance).  You "inject" the existing instance into the constructor.  I use this pattern for loading all my settings in my web projects.

Comment: Can you write an example of what in a perfect world you would like to do? Psuedocode would be helpful.

Comment: Or just have MenuUpgrade inherit from global stats... MenuUpgrade: GlobalStats ?

Comment: I've updated the code to show what I would like to do

Comment: You're want everything in global stats?

Comment: I see, you should definitely look at using dependency injection. It will change the way you think about programming, and solve this problem.  Autofac is a great library for c# to help manage the problems you are now running into.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look into it, if there no way to explain how it works?

Comment: I would probably change `GlobalStats` to a `Dictionary<string, float> Stats`, so that you can easily access it by key